# HABTM saving data problems

Tags: cakephp

I have a function Company Profile has a relationship HABTM to Users Controller with a joint table companies_users my functions is

```
ublic function company_profile(){
//$logo= $this->Upload->upload('/img/company_logo', $this->data['logo']['a'],null, array('image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'));
$log = $this->Auth->User('id');
    // retrieve the data of the currently logged in user
$user = $this->User->find('first',array(
            'conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$log),
            'recursive'=>1
));
    //pr($user);exit();
    if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')){
        //pr($this->request->data);exit;
        //pr($this->data);exit();
        if(isset($user['Company']) && !empty($user['Company'])){
        $newcompany = array();
        $this->User->Company->id = $user['Company'][0]['id'];
        $newcompany['Company'] = $this->data['Company'][0];
        $newcompany['Company']['id'] = $user['Company'][0]['id'];
        //pr($newcompany);exit();
        $this->User->Company->save($newcompany);
        }else{
        $this->User->Company->create();
        $newcompany = array();
        $newcompany['Company'] = $this->data['Company'][0];
        $newcompany['Company']['user_id'] = $log;
        pr($newcompany);exit();

        //newlogo = $this->request->data;
        //$newlogo['Company']['logo'] = $logo['urls']['0'];
        $this->User->Company->save($newcompany);
        //pr($newcompany);exit();
        $this->Session->setFlash('Company Profile Saved Successfully.');
        $this->redirect('/users/dashboard');

        }



    }else{
    $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $log);
    }
$this->loadModel('Category');
$categories = $this->Category->find('list');
$this->set(compact('user','categories'));

}
```

why is it it doesn't save on the joint table ? please help me on how it will be save in the joint table currently i have this array

Array
(
    [Company] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [category_id] => 1
            [name] => Infoperks Solutions
            [description] => Web development
            [user_id] => 1
        )

)

Comment: Array ( [Company] => Array ( [id] => [category_id] => 1 [name] => Infoperks Solutions [description] => Web development [user_id] => 1 )
 Is the id missing or you just made an error typing?

Comment: yeah it does not have an id yet since i PR it before saving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `'deep' => true` you can save the joined table data provided that you specified the model associationship. You can try to save the joined data using the following syntax:

```
$this->User->save($newcompany, array('deep' => true));
//instead of
//$this->User->Company->save($newcompany);
```

[This link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm) will surely help you to save your HABTM associated data.
Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: it will save but only for the joint table.